# Node modules won't import in my Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to import a node module installed through NPM inside a Vue.js single file component. Every time, whatever the module is, it won't work and throw an error such as `These depedencies were not found`. I'm following the install instructions right (at least I think) but I guess I'm missing something.

Example :

Trying to install the `swiper.js` module.
I did the NPM install in the right folder, then in the component where I want to use it I added the following lines such as explained on their website :

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';
```

And when I'm starting my server I get this error :

```
These dependencies were not found:

* swiper/css in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/ProductCarousel.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* swiper/vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/ProductCarousel.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save swiper/css swiper/vue
```

Edit :

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "swiper": "^7.0.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your `package.json`?

Comment: @tauzN Added it !

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. I would recommend deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm i`  again.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay, apart from `import 'swiper/css';` not needing to be imported.

You could try to delete your **node_modules** folder and running `npm install` again

Comment: keep in mind to delete the .lock-file as well.

Comment: @wittgenstein I would actually advice against that as all indirect dependencies can change and could screw up your code.

Answer (score 0):

In vue to make js script available you should import it in every component you would like to use in .
Or you can make it available globally by importing it in in main.js

For style you should import it in app.vue after opening style tag to make it global for every component style.

If we can take bootstrap as example.
In main.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
```

In app.vue

```
<style lang="scss">  @import './node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';</style>
```